# angular-cli - make http request to localhost (wamp)

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 app which has a PHP backend that resides inside wamp/www folder.

From my app, I'm doing the requests like this:

```
this.http.get('/server/connection.php')
```

When I serve my project, I try to add a proxy:

```
ng serve --proxy http://localhost
```

It tells me that `Proxy config file C:\wamp\www\fitnessMaster\localhost does not exist.`

How do I create that file, and where to put it? Or what is other solution to achieve what I want?
I'm using `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8`, with `node: 6.5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

`this.http.get('/server/connection.php')` looks strange to me. I guess you need a complete URL here. To check whether it works just hardcode it.

Besides I would recommend use *ng serve* and test your application in nodejs during development, because you have the nice feature of auto-change detection etc.

Later you can do ng build and copy the dist folder into your htdocs folder of your Apache server (WAMP).